# Flutter: ImagePicker: await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery) doesn't return

Tags: ios, flutter, image

When I triggers the pickimage function, it pops up the gallery view to select an image. And when I choose an image, the app returns to app view. But the pickimage function doesn't return, and hangs forever.
Here's my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:google_ml_kit/google_ml_kit.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Text Scanning Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late String result;
  File? _image;
  InputImage? inputImage;
  final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

  Future pickImageFromGallery() async {
    print("starting get image");
    final XFile? pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    //final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print("getting image.....");
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        print("file not null");
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(pickedFile.path);

        imageToText(inputImage);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future captureImageFromCamera() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(pickedFile.path);
        imageToText(inputImage);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future imageToText(inputImage) async {
    print("starting");
    result = '';

    final textDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.textDetector();
    print("loaded textDetector");
    final RecognisedText recognisedText = await textDetector.processImage(inputImage);
    print("loaded recognisedText");

    setState(() {
      String text = recognisedText.text;
      for (TextBlock block in recognisedText.blocks) {
        //each block of text/section of text
        final String text = block.text;
        print("block of text: ");
        print(text);
        for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
          //each line within a text block
          for (TextElement element in line.elements) {
            //each word within a line
            result += element.text + " ";
          }
        }
      }
      result += "\n\n";
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 100,
              child: TextField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                height: 70,
                width: 150,
                child: TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    pickImageFromGallery();
                  },
                  child: Text('Pick Image'),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my pubspec.yaml

```dart
name: text_scanning
description: A new Flutter project.


publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0-0 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  splash_screen_view: ^3.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_ml_kit: ^0.7.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.1+1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Here's podfile

```dart
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'
  pod 'Firebase'
end

post_install do |installer|
  # add these lines:
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=*]"] = "armv7"
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = $iOSVersion
  end

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    # add these lines:
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if Gem::Version.new($iOSVersion) > Gem::Version.new(config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'])
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = $iOSVersion
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's screenshot of my Info from xcode:
[note the privacy for gallery and camera][1]

I am at my wits end here, I followed every documentation, and it just doesn't even produce any error, and just hangs there.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC6aP.png

Comment: are you sure the imagePicker function failed or can the mlkit function possibly be faulty?

Comment: I tested with print statements. It doesn't make it to ImageToText function. It goes to pickImage, but the very next print statement never prints.

Comment: in some cases, the image file is too big for some algorithms tohandle. try using a lower qualit. you can specify that in the image picker function itself. Another tip: Don't use setstate around big blocks of code, rather use it only around the variable that should be updated in the ui.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.
I've found that this *only* happens when I include the `google_ml_kit` dependency, when I remove it from pubspec (and comment out the related code), the image picker works just fine and returns.
Also, at least in my case, this issue only occurs on iOS platforms.
@HarryWang any clue yet on the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this code on an iOS Simulator on an ARM based Mac (M1 / M1 Pro)?
If so, then the problem probably stems from a current bug in the iOS Simulator which only seems to reproduce when running with Rosetta translation (read more [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96761), and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71943)).

In your case, the `pubspec.yaml` file states `google_ml_kit` as a dependency, which forces the app to run using Rosetta, which in turn breaks the `image_picker` plugin.

Apple will probably fix this some time in the future, but in the meanwhile, you can workaround this issue by either running your app on a physical iOS device, *or* using an iOS Simulator with iOS version < 14.

To do so:

1. Open up Xcode
2. Go to Preferences.
3. Select the "Components" tab.
4. Mark the simulators you want.
5. Press "Check and Install Now".

Then:

1. Open up the Simulator app.
2. Select File > New Simulator
3. Select your device of choice, and make sure to select an iOS version < 14.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. It crashes when I try to select an image. I got "lost connection to device"